# Test if channel is empty (get buffer from channel?)

Tags: redux-saga

Is it possible to test if a channel is empty.

I do this:

```
function* watchRequests() {
  const requestChan = yield call(channel)
  requestChan.put({ type:'REQUEST', ... })
  while (true) {
      const action = yield take(requestChan);
      // i want to test if requestChan is empty and break
  }
}
```

I currently am thinking, i have to do a `yield flush(channel)` then if it returns something, then put them all back to the channel. Is this the only way?

```
const msgs = yield flush(channel);
if (actions.length) {
    for (const msg of msgs) {
        channel.put(msg);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I found another way. If i save the buffer that gets used, I can test `isEmpty()` on the buffer like this:

```
const buf = buffers.expanding(1);
const chan = yield call(channel, buf);

const isEmpty = buf.isEmpty();
```

Is there anyway to get the buffer from the channel so I don't have to save the buffer in a variable?

Comment: saving it in a var is the only way as far as I know. There's no method in Channel to check if it's empty.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg that's what I had to do. Appreciate your confirmation.